# Flutter Doctor gives Bad Cpu Type in executable

Tags: flutter, xcode13, macos-monterey, flutter-doctor, rosetta-2

I'm using Mac mini , MacOs monterey and m1 chip. When trying to setup flutter, it is giving error.
command: flutter doctor
o/p: /Users/admin/Desktop/flutter/bin/internal/shared.sh: line 229: /Users/admin/Desktop/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart: Bad CPU type in executable

I have tried below command but it is also not working,
Terminal command: sudo softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
Terminal output:
By using the agreetolicense option, you are agreeing that you have run this tool with the license only option and have read and agreed to the terms.
If you do not agree, press CTRL-C and cancel this process immediately.
**Rosetta 2 update is not available**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that , I had installed flutter sdk before installing the Rosetta. So that's why it was giving the above error. So, to resolve this, I removed the flutter sdk and installed rosetta first then again installed flutter and it worked properly.

Comment: i dont think you need to uninstall flutter. just enough to install rosetta

Answer (score 16):

you have to install rosetta first. In your terminal type:

```
/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

Answer (score 9):

I got this error on **MacOs VMware**
and finaly I realized that i was downloaded the **flutter sdk** for **arm Architecture**, but i need this for **x64 (intel) Architecture**.

Answer (score 2):

On macOs accidentally I downloaded **arm architecture** than **x64** version.
Download proper version as per the system requirements.

Answer (score 1):

run "softwareupdate --install-rosetta" in the terminal