# Flutter installation error on macOs monterey 12.6.5

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

After installing flutter on my macOs Monterey 12.6.5, flutter --version gives me the error /Users/hkouassi/Documents/flutter/bin/internal/shared.sh: line 238: /Users/hkouassi/Documents/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart: Bad CPU type in executable and also the installation of rosseta does not pass

flutter --version give an error
rosseta installation give also an error

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've installed the correct version for your CPU architecture?
If you're using a m1/m2 mac, you should install the arm/apple silicon version.

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69999682/flutter-doctor-gives-bad-cpu-type-in-executable) might help you.